# Checkbox changed it's state when the list view is scrolled down and up

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I have three listener for three checkboxes i should retrieve the values of all the three checkboxes say (true or false) and store those in a class. Later i will use the class to retrieve values. But my problem is when the listview is scrolled up and down my checkbox values which is created dynamically gets changed.

I will post the code which i have implemented, can anyone help me out to get rid of this ?

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ArrayList<Product> objects;
    ImageHolder imageHolder;
    ImageView imageview;

    ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        this.context = context;
        objects = products;
        this.imageHolder = new ImageHolder(context);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.store_visit_list, parent, false);
        }

        Product p = getProduct(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product)).setText(p.name);
        imageview=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        if(p.image.equals(null)||p.image.equals("null"))
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_default_sales_person);
        else
            imageHolder.DisplayImage(p.image, imageview);

        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        cb1.setTag(position);
        cb1.setChecked(p.is_order);

        CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
        cb2.setTag(position);
        cb2.setChecked(p.is_merchandising);

        CheckBox cb3 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
        cb3.setTag(position);
        cb3.setChecked(p.is_audit);
        return view;
    }

    Product getProduct(int position) {
        return ((Product) getItem(position));
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getObjects(){
        return objects;
    }
    OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).is_order=isChecked;
        }
    };
    OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList1 = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).is_merchandising = isChecked;
        }
    };
    OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList2 = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).is_audit = isChecked;

        }
    };
}
public class Product implements Serializable
{
      /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      String name;
      String position;
      int brandId;
      boolean is_order;
      boolean is_merchandising;
      boolean is_audit;
      String image;

      Product(String product_name,int brandid,boolean isorder,boolean ismerchandising, boolean isaudit,String photo) 
      {
        name = product_name;
        brandId=brandid;
        is_order = isorder;
        is_merchandising = ismerchandising;
        is_audit = isaudit;
        image=photo;
      }
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return brandId+"#"+(is_audit ? 1 : 0 )+"#"+(is_merchandising ? 1 : 0)+"#"+(is_order ? 1 : 0);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you accept my answer? I answered first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add, in getView:

```
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList1);
cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList2);
```

For simplicity, you can directly setTag with the "product" object.

Comment: I should declare like this right ?     CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
   cb2.setTag(position);
   cb2.setChecked(p.is_merchandising);
   cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList1);

Comment: it works after placing listener in getview method thanks for your reply:)

Comment: Yes, and the same for the others checkbox. If you don't, the CheckBox will never fire any listener.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the OnCheckedChangeListeners, but not setting them on the checkboxes, so they never get called.

Comment: i couldn't get you at first. After Kevinrob answer i tried in my code and it works hence i marked his answer as correct one. I couldn't select both of you peoples answer as correct hence !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't update the Product object in the arrayList when you do :

```
getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).is_order=isChecked;
```

Try this in your listenner:

```
//Retrieve the product object from arrayList
Product p = getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag());
//Modify the object
p.is_order = isChecked;
//Update the ArrayList<Product> objects at desired position
objects.set((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), p);
```

For info, when the element in listView is no more displayed, it is recycled and recreated (getView() called )when it will be displayed again.

Comment: So instead of getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).is_order=isChecked; i should set the above three lines so that the onclicklistener will be updated right ?